# Regex C# problem

Tags: c#, regex

I'm sure there is a simple solution, but I just seem to be missing it.

I need a regex to do the following:

`asdf.txt;qwer` should match `asdf.txt`

`"as;df.txt";qwer` should match `as;df.txt`

As you can see, I need to match up to the semi-colon, but if quotes exist(when there is a semi-colon in the value), I need to match inside the quotes. Since I am looking for a file name, there will never be a quote in the value.

My flavor of regex is C#.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you have escaped quotes (like \" or "") inside the quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"[^"]+"(?=;)|[^;]+(?=;)
```

This matches text within double quotes followed by a semicolon OR text followed by a semicolon. The semicolon is NOT included in the match.

EDIT: realized my first attempt will match the quotes. The following expression will exclude the quotes, but uses subexpressions.

```
"([^"]+)";|([^;]+);
```

Comment: I've never used that ?= notation.  What is it called and what flavors support it?

Comment: It is 'look-ahead equals'. It's supported by at least .NET and JavaScript. My favorite site to test regular expressions is http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx. It supports multiple engines, including JavaScript and .NET.

Comment: You got me on the right path.  Here is the regex I chose `(?<=")?[^"]+(?="?;)`

Comment: Awesome! I was just looking for the 'look-behind' (?<=), which I suspect is .NET only. I don't see it in my JavaScript reg exp reference.

Comment: I use a tool called Expresso which is free.  It breaks your regex into a tree structure so you can pick it apart easier

Comment: I had to tweek it a little, because my string had another ; in it.  Here is the final version `(?<=^("?))[^"]+?(?=\1;)`

Answer (score 1):

This should do you:

```
(".*"|.*);
```

It technically matches the semicolon as well, but you can either chop that off or just use the backreference (if C# supports backreferences)

Answer (score 1):

This will match up to a `;` if there are no quotes or the quoted text followed by a `;` if there are quotes.

```
("[^"]+";|[^;]+;)
```

Comment: This match will include the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use regex, you could just use the C# string method contains:

```
string s = "asdf.txt;qwer";
string s1 = "\"as;df.txt\";qwer";

return s.Contains("asdf.txt"); //returns true
return s1.Contains("\"as;df.txt\""); //returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the two explicit strings asdf.txt and as;df.txt these can then simply be your two regex epressions.  So something like the following.

```
Matches matches = Regex.Matches('asdf.txt;qwer',"asdf.txt");
```

and

```
Matches matches = Regex.Matches('"as;df.txt";qwer',"as;df.txt");
```

Enjoy!

Comment: they are not those specific strings.  They could be any valid file name